# Set a master font in PowerPoint to a non-predefined font

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

Trying to set up a custom font pairing in the Slide Master view in PowerPoint 365 for Mac (version 16.26). Microsoft says on its help page that:

> You don't have to choose from the pre-defined font pairs on the menu;
>   choose **Customize Fonts** at the bottom of the menu to select your own
>   fonts.

[image]

However, I have scrolled up and down the Fonts drop-down menu, and there is no **Customize Fonts** option. Am I missing something?

[image: Screen shot of PowerPoint Slide Master, Fonts menu]
[image]

Comment: The only thing you're missing is a Windows version of PowerPoint.  Unfortunately, the Mac version can't create font themes, which is what you need to do.

Comment: True, but it's not hard to create a custom Font Theme, as it's just a simple XML file. I have explained how to do this here: https://superuser.com/a/1558559/17390